# Como hago para que se pueda ver mi menu desplegable ya que me lo esta tapando mi slider?

Tags: php, html5, css3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>InveFacil</title>
    <!--GOOGLE FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP MAIN STYLES -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--FONTAWESOME MAIN STYLE -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--SLIDER CSS CLASES -->
    <link href="assets/Slides-SlidesJS-3/examples/playing/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--CUSTOM STYLE -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/menu.css"/>
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center"  class="logo"><h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto Mono',monospace; background-color: teal;" >
    InveFacil</h1></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Perfil Trabajador</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=consultarTrabajador">Consultar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=insertarTrabajador">Agregar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=editarTrabajador">Editar</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="index2.php?pag=consultarProducto">Consultar</a></li>
                     <li><a href="index2.php?pag=insertarProducto">Agregar</a></li>
                     <li><a href="index2.php?pag=editarProducto">Editar</a></li>

                 </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Proveedor</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=consultarProveedor">Consultar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=insertarProveedor">Agregar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=editarProveedor">Editar</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Reportes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=listarTrabajador">Trabajador</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=listarProducto">Producto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php?pag=listarProveedor">Proveedor</a></li>
                    </ul>

            <li><a href="salir.php">Cerrar</a> </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi slider

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>InveFacil</title>
    <!--GOOGLE FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP MAIN STYLES -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--FONTAWESOME MAIN STYLE -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--SLIDER CSS CLASES -->
    <link href="assets/Slides-SlidesJS-3/examples/playing/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--CUSTOM STYLE -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

 <div id="slides">
        <img src="assets/img/slider/images/inventario8.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="assets/img/slider/images/inventario7.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="assets/img/slider/images/inventario6.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="assets/img/slider/images/inventario9.jpg" alt="" />

    </div>
    <!-- END SLIDER SECTION -->

 <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- CORE BOOTSTRAP LIBRARY -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SLIDER SCRIPTS LIBRARY -->
    <script src="assets/Slides-SlidesJS-3/examples/playing/js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPT-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#slides').slidesjs({
                width: 1024,
                height: 688,
                play: {
                    active: true,
                    auto: true,
                    interval: 4000,
                    swap: true
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas traer tu Menú desplegable al frente puedes hacer lo siguiente.

Ten presente que Existe el eje Y y el eje X, pero también hay un eje Z que permite traer los elementos hacia delante y atrás.

En CSS existe una etiqueta llamada z-index que permite mostrar y ocultar valores Según tu necesidad.

Ejemplo:

Si quieres traer tu menú al frente usa en la clase de tu Menú o ID del mismo z-index: 1000 para que siempre este adelante de todo.

Si quieres que se quede por atrás de cualquier otro elemento usa z-index: -1000 para que quede siempre por detrás de tu contenido.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvió mucho tu ayuda ya corregí el inconveniente